# Persistant "bash: /home/XXX/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory" in terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, terminal

I've installed ruby on rails and have checked all are current. One thing thats been bothering me is this constant "bash: /home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory" in my terminal.

How do I remove this "bash: /home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory"?
To be honest I don't know what it means but I wish I could remove it as rails and ruby are current versions.

```
bash: /home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Make sure this directory or file exist in you system. `/home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

Comment: It doesn't exist, so I created the folder and it didn't do anything

Comment: Have you got problem solved? or what problem are you facing?

Comment: No, the problem still exist. There's still a persistent "bash: /home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory". I want this to go away from my terminal and I don't know how

Comment: Have you checked each directory mention above error? e.g. does elementary directory exist in /home directory

Comment: do one thing find this line `/home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in following files of `/etc/` directory.
`bashrc` and `profile`

Comment: The /scripts/rvm did not exist, all that existed was /home/elementary/.rvm

Comment: Okay please create both scripts and rvm, one more thing create scripts directory and rvm as a directory and a file named rvm and try

Comment: Also have you try to find  /home/elementary/.rvm/scripts/rvm in following files of /etc/ directory. `bashrc` and `profile`

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, I have been able to find a rvm in profile, I don't see a bashrc. Though if I go into the home directory, there is an elementary directory with folder .rvm and nothing else.

Comment: I have been able to find a rvm in the profile directory and I copied and pasted it into the new rvm folder I created in the home directory.

Comment: This is what the rvm file I found in profile contained, http://pastebin.com/JAPJfSDj

Comment: Hmm, go through this link and try to install this [http://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-2-1-on-centos-rhel/](http://tecadmin.net/install-ruby-2-1-on-centos-rhel/). As per your rvm file this indicate your installation is not successful. `# Load RVM if it is installed, try user then root install.
  if [[ -s "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm" ]] ; then
    source "$rvm_path/scripts/rvm"`

Comment: It linux distro elementary OS

Comment: Could you explain how you installed that?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly but its okay now, I reinstalled the whole distro again. Thanks for the help everyone, I think it might have been the rvm I installed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the below to your .bashrc

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```

Add the below to your .bash_profile

```
source ~/.profile
source ~/.bashrc

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you installed RVM at some point, and for some reason it isn't correctly installed any more.

Read [the installation instructions](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) carefully and follow the diagnostics and debugging steps.

The authors of RVM specifically say in that page to *NOT* follow other tutorials on installing RVM. They understand how it works better than anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your installation is not perfect. Please follow the below commands

```sh
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
=====Install RVM stable with ruby:
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
rvm --version
```